# If I counter a planeswalker what happens to them?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I counter a planeswalkers activation, with say something like [Sinister Sabotage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSinister%20Sabotage%5d) or [Unwind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnwind%5d), does the planeswalker return to the players hand, or do they die?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “planeswalker activation”? Normally I would expect that phrase to mean activating a planeswalker’s loyalty ability; but that wouldn’t make as much sense in the context of this question. Do you mean casting a planeswalker?

Answer (score 1):

A planeswalker is a spell while it is on the stack. Any spell you counter will go to the graveyard unless the counterspell says otherwise, such as with [Remand](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRemand%5d). Thus, a planeswalker will be put into the graveyard. Not sure if this is a question confused on whether planeswalkers are treated differently than other spells or not? If you had some other reasoning why you think a planeswalker might be treated differently than another spell, feel free to add it to your question! It may help newer players to understand it better in the future.

Comment: And although it goes to the graveyard, it doesn't "die". That term refers to creatures that go from the battlefield to a graveyard.

Comment: Planeswalkers can "die" (see rule 700.4), but only when moving from the battlefield.

Comment: My apologies, i didn't even realize he said "die" in the question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot counter a planeswalker activation with Sinister Sabotage or Unwind - a planeswalker activation is not a spell. You can counter a planeswalker spell when it's on the stack (i.e. when it's being cast), but not the activation after it's resolved.

To counter a planeswalker activation you need something like [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d), which counters *activated abilities*. If a planeswalker activation is countered this way, it still loses (or gains, depending on the ability) loyalty counters, but aside from that nothing happens - it stays in play.

Comment: Countering a planeswalker activation doesn't change the loyalty counters (they are added/removed as a cost)